# python defining function ('None')

Tags: python

Python Newbie here!

```
def x():
 print ('y')

x()
```

This produces the output-
'y'

BUT

```
def x():
 print ('y')
a = x()
print (a)
```

This produces 'y' and 'None' at the end. Why the none at the end?

Comment: Because the function returns nothing explicitly so it defaults to None. When you do `a = x()` you store `x`'s return value into `a`. Since there was no explicit return value, it got None.

Comment: `print` != `return`

Comment: the first code also got nothing to return. Why doesn't that show none?

Comment: Do you see a `print` of the return value somewhere in your first code? No. You don't even catch the reurn value. So why should the program print `None`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the function x () is returning nothing, hence None.

return 'y' to get print of 'a'.

Hope this helps.